# Cómo retornar listas que tienen listas anidadas?

Tags: c#, json, xml

Hola tengo un problema al querer retornar una lista que tiene anidada otra, el problema es el siguiente.

Tengo dos clases: "Encabezado" y "Detalle", su definición es la siguiente:

```
class encabezado {
    public string IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public List<Detalle> Items { get; set; }
}
class Detalle {
    public string IdProducto { get; set; }
    public string Producto { get; set; }
}
```

La lleno y la retorno con el siguiente metodo :

```
public List<encabezado> resumen()
    {
        var ListDetalle = new List<Detalle>();
        var ListEncabezado = new List<encabezado>{
               new encabezado{
                IdCliente="1",
                Nombre="Prueba",
                Items= ListDetalle
               },
               new encabezado{
                   IdCliente="2",
                Nombre="Prueba2",
                Items= ListDetalle
               }
        };

        ListDetalle.Add(new Detalle
        {
            IdProducto = "1",
            Producto = "Producto para lista uno"
        });
        ListDetalle.Add(new Detalle
        {
            IdProducto = "2",
            Producto = "Producto para lista dos"
        });

        return ListEncabezado;
    }
```

Al momento de invocar ese método y mostrarlo en pantalla me retorna la siguiente cadena el cual esta malo porque me mezcla los detalle no importando los encabezados:

```
IdCliente : 1 ,Nombre : Prueba, Items: 

IdProducto : 1,Producto   : Producto para lista uno,IdProducto : 2,Producto   : Producto para lista dos

IdCliente : 2,Nombre : Prueba2,Items: 

IdProducto : 1,Producto   : Producto para lista uno,IdProducto : 2,Producto   : Producto para lista dos
```

**Cadena como deberia retornar:**

```
IdCliente : 1 ,Nombre : Prueba, Items: IdProducto : 1,Producto   : Producto para lista uno

IdCliente : 2,Nombre : Prueba2,Items: IdProducto : 2,Producto   : Producto para lista dos
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el resultado esperado?

Comment: Exactamente cómo lo muestras en pantalla? Es el resultado que debería arrojar, en ningún momento has puesto una nueva lista para el cliente con ID 2, en su lugar has asignado la misma referencia en la lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<encabezado> resumen()
{
    encabezado e1 =  new encabezado();
    encabezado e2 =  new encabezado();

    e1.ListDetalle.Add(new Detalle
    {
        IdProducto = "1",
        Producto = "Producto para lista uno"
    });

    e2.ListDetalle.Add(new Detalle
    {
        IdProducto = "2",
        Producto = "Producto para lista dos"
    });

    var ListEncabezado = new List<encabezado>{e1, e2};
    return ListEncabezado;
}
```

Comment: Y esto como funciona?

Comment: Cada uno de los objeto cabecera tiene su propia lista de detalles. Despues de esto los agrego a una lista de objetos cabecera.

Comment: Creo que eso deberías ponerlo en la respuesta para que el op entienda lo que haces.